# finding $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such as $z^n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find which $z \in \mathbb{C}$ work such as $a_n = z^n$ converges.

Here's my thought process, but I don't think I'm following the right direction.

$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \exists \: r \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \: \theta \in \: ] -\pi ; \pi ] $ such as $z = re^{i\theta}$

$z^n$ converges $⇔ \Im(z^n) $ converges and $\Re(z^n)$ converges $⇔$ $r^n \cos(n\theta)$ converges and $r^n \sin(n\theta)$ converges.

However I'm stuck now. Any ideas?

Comment: Your approach can work: it all depends on the value of $r$ (why?). Try testing some values of $r$, e.g. what happens if $r=1$?

Comment: @Dave it will diverge if $r = 1$, but I can't see how a different value of $r$ will make it converge, since the $\cos$ or the $\sin$ will oscillate anywhere between $-1$ and $1$

Comment: Since cosine and sine are bounded they will be irrelevant as $n\to\infty$ when $r<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z|<1$, then $(z^n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $0$, as $\lim_{n \to +\infty} |z^n| = 0$ implies that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} z^n = 0$.

If $|z|>1$, then $(z^n)_{n \geq 1}$ does not converge, since $\lim_{n \to +\infty} |z^n| = +\infty$.

Lastly (credits to kingW3 on the comment below): if $(z^n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges and $|z|=1$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} z^{n+1} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} z^n$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} z^{n+1} = z \lim_{n \to +\infty} z^n$ implies that $z=1$, as we can cancel the limit result.

Comment: If $z^n$ converges and $|z|=1$ we have $\lim z^{n+1}=z\lim z^n=\lim z^n$ so $z=1$ since $\lim z^n\neq 0,\infty$.

Comment: Nice, I should have realized this fast. I added your comment to the answer and made it CW.